# How to extract a number (price) from description

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, substring, postgresql-9.1

Item price is in format

```
999,99

999 -  1 ..4 digits 
, - comma sign marks decimal point 
99 - 2 digits after price
```

Postgres 9.1 table contains char(50) type column.
This column may contain price in separate word separated by spaces. Like

```
Product 12,99 blue
Another product 4,59
This is third 124,39 item price
```

How to extract price from description in select statement ? For those 3 rows result should be

```
12,99
4,59
124,39
```

Using

PostgreSQL 9.1.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 64-bit

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan your upgrade to a supported version (e.g. 11) now. If you can't do that, you should at least [upgrade to the latest 9.1 minor version](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.1.2&to=9.1.24&keywords=)

Comment: I'm using Debian squueze and this upgrade is not available in this OS.

Comment: Of course it is: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/

Comment: You [shouldn't be using `char`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29) either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using `substring(yourString FROM yourPattern)` function.

```
SELECT substring(columnName FROM '\d{1,4},\d{2}') 
FROM tableName
```

Regex explanation:

`d{1,4}` - at least one digit, but not more than four digits

`,` - comma

`d{2}` - exactly two digits

Comment: Thank you. This also returns price if it is not separated by spaces like `product12,33`  returns also 12,33

Comment: @Andrus you are welcome. If you would like not to much such cases, you may use `SELECT substring(columnName FROM ' \d{1,4},\d{2} ')  FROM tableName
WHERE substring(columnName FROM ' \d{1,4},\d{2} ') IS NOT NULL` or `SELECT substring(columnName FROM '\s\d{1,4},\d{2}\s')  FROM tableName
WHERE substring(columnName FROM '\s\d{1,4},\d{2}\s') IS NOT NULL`